# Managing Facebook Pixel and Google Analytics Events between Development, Stating and Production Environment

Tags: google-analytics, opencart, development-environment, production-environment, facebook-pixel

We are using Opencart for our store and having trouble with Facebook Pixel, Google Analytics and Events between the different environments of Development, Stating and Product.

How are you guys managing the setup and avoiding the wrong data from misfires from the dev and staging servers?